# Array of arrays with vowels/consonants as elements

Tags: arrays, ruby, methods

I just started with Ruby. I need to build a method that takes two letters as arguments and returns an array of two arrays containing the same two letters and the letters included between them. The first array should contain only vowels whereas the second array only consonants. E.g.:

```
def alphamek('a', 'd')
```

should return:

```
[['a'], ['b', 'c', 'd']]
```

I tried this:

```
def alphamek(letter1, letter2) 
first_array = (letter1..letter2).scan[aeiou].to_a
second_array = (letter1..letter2).scan[^aeiou].to_a
multi_array = [[first_array], [second_array]]
end
```

but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: This is probably a typo on your part, but `letter1` and `letter2` should not be string literals, i.e., remove the `'`.

Comment: Corrected, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You are calling `scan` on the Range `(letter1..letter2)`. That method does not exist.
What you can do is call `select` since Ranges are enumerable, see the documentation on an explanation for `select`: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-select

Here's a working alternative that closely resembles your approach (as you intended it to work):

```
def alphamek(letter1, letter2)
  vowels = 'aeiou'
  # select all letters that are vowels
  first_array = (letter1..letter2).select { |letter| vowels.include?(letter) }
  # reject all letters that are vowels
  second_array = (letter1..letter2).reject { |letter| vowels.include?(letter) }
  return first_array, second_array # => [[...], [...]]
end
```

`reject` is simply the opposite of select, I prefer to use it instead of inverting the condition.

Anyway, there is an even better approach to this partitioning:

```
def alphamek(letter1, letter2)
  vowels = 'aeiou'
  (letter1..letter2).partition { |letter| vowels.include?(letter) }
end
```

This does the same as the other approach. `partition` splits the enumerable into two arrays, the first one contains the values for which the block evaluates to true, the second those for which it evaluates to false.
See `partition` in the docs: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition

Comment: How about `vowels = 'aeiou'`?

Comment: Even better! Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 3):

Not really that hard if you work it from a regular expression perspective and leverage a tool like [`partition`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-partition):

```
VOWEL = /[aeiou]/i

def alphamek(a, b)
  (a..b).partition { |l| VOWEL.match(l) }
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way of doing that is to use the methods [Array#&](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-26) and [Array#-](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-2D).

```
VOWELS = %w| a e i o u |
  #=> [“a“, ”e”, ”i”, ”o”, ”u”]

def doit(first_letter, last_letter)
  letters = (first_letter..last_letter).to_a
  [VOWELS & letters, letters - VOWELS]
end

doit 'f', 't'
  #=> [["i", "o"], ["f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t"]]
doit 'f', 'o'
  #=> [["i", "o"], ["f", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n"]]
doit 'v', 'z'
  #=> [[], ["v", "w", "x", "y", "z"]]
```

Comment: It's called _array difference_ because `[1, 1, 2, 2] - [1]` returns `[2, 2]` instead of `[2]`.

Comment: Thanks for setting me straight, @Stefan. I should have noticed that considering my fondness for a method `Array#difference`.